# Web App Securiy With LDAP

Tags: database, security, authentication, ldap

When designing my web apps, I have always implemented user authentication with database e.g. MySQL.

However, you hear every now and then of LDAP Server authentication and so on. Does the latter provide better security than plain old DB-backed authentication? If so, in what scenario will a developer need to consider using AD for authentication; if not why the need at all?

I am not interested in mere debate. I just want to learn from experienced programmers and experts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's designed to store users so:

1. your application doesn't have to store credentials, groups etc. you can outsource the responsibility
2. if you have one source of users you can connect multiple company's applications to it (mail, billing system, door entrance system etc) and reject grants for all those places at once when your employee loses permission (for example quit the company). you can also have one place to manage grants to every application in company. your db affects only your application
3. ldap should be faster than db as it doesn't support transactions

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Piotrek for the benefits of using an LDAP directory instead of a DB.

An LDAP directory has several mechanisms to protect credentials out of the box, including strong hashing schemes, so you do not need to implement them in your application.

I'd like to point out that using an LDAP directory server does not always mean to use AD. AD is very often used in enterprise to centralize credentials and authentication, but will not allow to store anything else specific to the webApps.

But as a general recommendation, I would suggest to stop trying to create any datastore for credentials. Applications should delegate authentication to a dedicated standard based authentication service, or reuse social logins. The OpenID Connect protocol is designed for that. Then it's perfectly fine to store application specific data related to the users in a dedicated database, i.e. MySQL.